# integrating swing with javaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2

i'm making an application with javaFX 2.0. i wanted to add fileExplorer (found on http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/duvanslabbert/92-java-file-explorer.html) given that the file explorer is swing.

in the main stage , group root i cant add the file explorer as it's not a javafx node

```
    FileExplorer fe = new FileExplorer(new File("D:/"));
    myVbox.getChildren().add(fe);
```

i get this error :

```
The method add(Node) in the type List<Node> is not applicable for the arguments (FileExplorer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swing in JavaFX application has limitations and should be avoided.

There are two ways to solve your problem:

1. Create a Swing application with 2 parts: FileExplorer and JFXPanel for all JavaFX content.
   See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html
2. Use JavaFX TreeView control and populate it with filesystem info yourself.